# Flutter/Dart http request response with a value

Tags: flutter, dart, response

I have an app which is using http request for php server.

But I have a problem here.

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
final response =
    await client.get(Uri.parse('https://meshcurrent.online/get_1userdrive.php'));

// Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

       // A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
    List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
     }
```

I have a code like this. I am getting datas from the server. But I want to send a value to php server. and get datas depend on the value.

For instance, I will send username to the php server and I will get the datas about the username parameter. My php codes works but the problem is in flutter code.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Take a look at post request in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

If youre tryting to send parameters over a get, you could use something like:

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://meshcurrent.online/get_1userdrive.php?userId=5'));

  if (urlCallResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
    return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  } else {
    ...
  }
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

Here is an example on how to do a **post**:

```
 final response = await post(
  Uri.parse(
      'http://.../PostCall'),
  headers: {
    'authorization': getBasicAuth(username, password),
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: json.encode(jobFormValue),
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
}
```

**getBasicAuth** function:

```
String getBasicAuth(String username, String password) {
  return 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'))}';
}
```

Comment: I have a code to post request to send datas with the request. THe code:                           
       final uriA = 'https://meshcurrent.online/get_1userdrive.php';
                var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                map['whichUser'] = "1rank";

                http.Response response = await http.post(
                  Uri.parse(uriA),
                  body: map,
                ); I want to mix this code and the main questions code. Please help me for this way. It is important for me.

Comment: I just add a post example to the answer. Let me know if it works